# Ubuntu sound too quiet or distorted if volume increased

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, equalizer

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 right now, Dual boot with Windows on XPS 15.

Something I've noticed which I don't exactly understand, is Ubuntu causing speakers to be quiet or distorted. It's not that the speaker's can't go louder - on Windows they can go REALLY LOUD while still being good quality. On Ubuntu, if I start hitting 0 dB, anything above that is terribly distorted, while 0 dB is still far from loud. What seems ridiculous to me, is that I can connect a Bluetooth speaker, make it really quiet, but make audio in Ubuntu loud enough, so even though the Speaker barely plays anything, it's terribly distorted - so it's not Speaker's that can't go loud, it's Ubuntu that adds distortions to everything for some reason.

How come Windows can play everything so much louder without any problems and on Ubuntu you can run into terrible distortions while it's still pretty damn quiet? Can I somehow increase the volume without causing distortions?

Currently, I'm using PulseEffects (which I NEED for the sound to be usable, by default my Headphones, Bluetooth Speaker and Built-in Speakers sound horrible, so I needed to create a PulseEffects setup for each of them to make them sound acceptable), and I ended up just setting a Limiter to avoid distortions, but 0 dB limit is just way too low - everything is still pretty damn quiet at that volume on Ubuntu, but if anything goes above 0 dB it immidiately gets completely distorted.

Is there any way to fix it, and worst case scenario, are there any other distros that can manage the sound better?

Comment: I've just tried this solution: https://markandruth.co.uk/2017/10/18/fixing-ubuntu-16-04-massive-internal-microphone-distortion
Will update if it works

Comment: I have the same issue. My volume settings in any screen i can find are set at 100% or above to hear much of anything. All devices on alsamixer, same in pavucontrol. the meters show high volume and start to clip if i push the volumes beyond a 100%, but the actual output is still very low. In windows the volume is plenty loud.

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and at the prompt, type `alsamizer`.

You will see a view with several amplitude faders. Look for the sound card associated with your speakers. If it is low, set it to unity gain.

Comment: Unfortunately, the card is set to 100 - I can only lower it which makes the output more quiet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).